# Error when creating OS X installer on USB drive via Terminal

Tags: macos, install

Hi I'm getting this error when I paste into the Terminal

```
sudo: /Applications/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sudo: & createinstallmedia: with colons... Is that OK?

Comment: @Tetsujin He's pasting the error message, which is coming from sudo ("sudo:" meaning "sudo returned") and the second colon meaning, "the following relates to the text before the colon". He didn't type it in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the path "/Applications/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia" doesn't exist. *createinstallmedia* is an executable to create bootable El Capitan installer media. You either moved/renamed "Install OS X El Capitan.app" (or the file createinstallmedia) or it doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use [DiskMaker X](http://diskmakerx.com), a free app, with which you create a bootable USB stick from the installer file without having to use Terminal. I've used it since Mac OS X Lion 10.7, when Apple first went to a download-only model and never had a problem with it.